# How to map screen coordinates to individual Tiles in a rotated Tilemap?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, isometric

I'm trying to figure out how to properly calculate a cursor's location relative to a rotated `Tilemap`.  First, a couple pictures to illustrate the problem.

```
Camera rotation: 0
Tilemap rotation: 0
```

[image]
Everything looks good and works great, except we're wanting the tiles to have a psuedo-3d perspective, which means rotating them along the x axis:

```
Camera Rotation: 0
Tilemap rotation: 60
```

[image]
This gets us our perspective, however besides a narrow band of tiles near the middle, the calculation for finding the tile stops working:
[image]

So far I've tried two different approaches that both net the same result:

```cs
var touchPosition = getScreenPosition();
var worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPosition);
worldPosition.z = 0;
var cellPosition = tilemap.WorldToCell(position);
```

Notably I'm having to do some z-axis manipulation to account for the camera position which I suspect could be part of my initial problem.  Instead I swapped over to doing raycasts to find my intersection:

```cs
var plane = new Plane(Vector3.back, Vector3.zero);

var touchPosition = getScreenPosition();
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, 0f));
if (plane.Raycast(ray, out float hit))
{
    var point = ray.GetPoint(hit);
    var cellPosition = tilemap.WorldToCell(point);
}
```

That eliminated the need to adjust the z-axis, however with the `Tilemap` rotated I still fail to find the correct `Tile`.  Interestingly, if I also rotate the `Camera` itself, everything goes back to working again without the perspective and being offset (since the camera's physical location hasn't changed).

```
Camera rotation: 60
Tilemap rotation: 60
```

[image]

My suspicion is that despite the raycast finding a valid hit, `WorldToCell()` isn't taking the transform's rotation into account when doing its conversion.  I couldn't find the source for that particular function so if that's available somewhere I'll happily start there.  Besides that, if someone can help point me to the math I might need to do in order to get this calculation correct, that'd be wonderful.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this was incredibly simple: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/5220 had the info I needed, specifically the sentence:

> Here is the traditional version with horizontal hexes that are effectively squished in the vertical axis to make a pseudo-isometric look.

Instead of rotating the `Tilemap` 60 degrees, I simply set its Y-scale to `0.5` and voila, everything worked perfectly.